# How to find UTM in iphone application by programming?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one iphone application in which I want to find UTM value using locationmanager. Is it possible?

Comment: Ahh.. Google helped: Universal Transcerse Mercator coordinate system:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this function is not available in the SDK.

You could write a function to do it yourself. There is some description of the Mathematics involved [here](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/utmformulas.htm) - although it looks non-trivial.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Acctually I have seen some application in app store is possible.

Comment: Hiya, yes - I see. I would bet that that they are performing the calculation in the app using something similar to the link I gave above.